# Why we need heap spray to layout heap?

Tags: security, binary, heap-memory, exploit

As we know, the heap spray model is just like:

```
var shellCode = "XXXXXXXXXXX";    //shellcode
var nops = 0x0a0a0a0a;    //slide code
while (nops.length < 0x100000)
    nops += nops;
nops = nops.substring(...);
nops = nops+shellcode;
var memory = new Array();
for (var i=0; i < 200; i++) 
    memory[i] += nops

var str = '';
while(str.length < 256) str+= '\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a';
str = str + "\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c";
bufferOverFlow(str);
```

but why we can'y do it like this? Just use the address of the allocated heap to set our shellCode.

```
var shellCode = "XXXXXXXXXXX";    //shellcode
shellCode = shellCode.substring(...);

var str = '';
while(str.length < 256) str+= '\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a';
str = str + &shellCode;
bufferOverFlow(str);
```

Comment: You need to ensure the alignment of adjacent sections of memory of *differing* bucket sizes so they can be coalesced.